# Trouble with a substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm struggling to show that
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{1+x^2} dx $$ 
to
$$ -\pi + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1+\cos^2(\theta))^{-1}d\theta$$
with $x=\cos(\theta)$

I'm aware I'm missing something obvious but I end up with a stray $\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Are you sure of the limits of integration after the substitution? It seems weird to integrate over the whole circle.  I would have thought that one of them would be zero, but maybe that's where the $-\pi$ out front comes in ...

Comment: If you show the details of what you have already done and where the stray $\sin \theta$ you are getting is coming from that would be helpful.

Comment: I would instead let $u=x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

After the usual substitution, you get

$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2\theta}{1+\cos^2 \theta}d\theta = \int_0^\pi \frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{1+\cos^2 \theta}d\theta = \int_0^\pi -1 + \frac{2}{1+\cos^2\theta} = \\-\pi + \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{1+\cos^2\theta}d\theta.
$$

In the last steps I was using that

$$
\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} = -1 + \frac{2}{1+x^2}
$$

and that $\frac{1}{1+\cos^2\theta}$ is an even function.

Comment: But $\sqrt{sin^{2}\theta}$ is in the numerator, is it not?

Also, I am positive it's between $\pi$ and $-\pi$, unless the question has a typo.

Comment: Yep, for some reason I thought the exponent was $-1/2$ and mentally put it in the denominator. In that case you will end up with a $-\sin^2\theta$ in the numerator.

Comment: i have edited my answer.

Comment: Marvellous, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $u=\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ in the calculation. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2\theta}d\theta&=&\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}}d\theta\\
&=&\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{2}{3+\cos(2\theta)}d\theta\\
&=&\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3+\cos(\theta)}d\theta\\
&=&2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{3+\cos(\theta)}d\theta\\
&=&4\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{3+\cos(\theta)}d\theta\\
&=&4\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{3+\frac{1-\tan^2(\frac\theta2)}{1+\tan^2(\frac\theta2)}}d\theta\\
&=&4\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{3+\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\frac{2}{1+u^2}du\\
&=&8\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{4+2u^2}du\\
&=&4\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{2+u^2}du\\
&=&4\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac{u}{\sqrt2}\bigg|_0^\infty\\
&=&\sqrt2\pi.
\end{eqnarray}